# Can antimatter be used to annihilate radio-actives elements (e.g. at Fukushima)?

Tags: antimatter, radioactivity

Can antimatter be produced in enough quantity to be used to annihilate the radio-actives elements of the Fukushima disaster (and of any others, such as Tchernobyl) ?

Answer (score 4):

No. The easiest type of antimatter to create, antihydrogen, is insanely expensive to make. NASA estimated in 1999 that it would cost $62.5 *trillion* to make *one gram* of antihydrogen. We could no doubt make it cheaper these days, but not by enough to make it reasonable. The Chernobyl reactor core had 192 tonnes of fuel in it, and a pretty significant portion of it was released.

Even if you could, it wouldn't help you. It seems like your idea is to make the "anti-" counterpart of radioactive elements and collide them together, right? But this would require targeting the specific radioactive atoms (an impossible task), and even if you *could* do it, the products of the annihilation would themselves activate the surroundings and make *more* radioactive materials.

Comment: In addition to this, there are simply no feasible routes to make anti-atoms that are bigger than hydrogen.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Isn't it enough (in the goal to annihilate) to produce an antineutrons material or beam?

Comment: @Chris You mentioned: "the products of the annihilation would themselves activate the surroundings and make more radioactive materials". 
Isn't the result of matter antimatter collision pure photons ?
Isn't the fission chain reaction only the result only (beside its "self fission") of a neutron hitting a nucleus? If so, how can antimatter produce make more radioactive materials?

Comment: @HeyStackExchange It's not just photons. Anything that's accessible energetically is fair game. Even photons, at high enough energy, can fragment nuclei and make more radioactive material. A beam of antineutrons is pretty certain to make everthing in the area radioactive, not get rid of the radioactive elemebts already there.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty RHIC has produced antihelium nuclei. It seems conceivable we could capture a few of them and make proper antihelium atoms if we were willing to throw enough money at the problem. ;)